# .Net Compact Framework - is there any way in the SerialPort class to set the RTS control to TOGGLE?

Tags: compact-framework, serial-port

I found very annoying the fact that the SerialPort class in the .NET Framework doesn't allow to set the rts control to TOGGLE.

There is a property called RTSEnable that lets me control directly the status of the RTS signal, but in a Compact Framework app there is not much precision to make it work well.

Another solution can be to write a class that calls unmanaged APIs and set the rts control via the DCB structure, but I don't like it since I am using some external libraries that need to reference to a SerialPort instance.

Have you any other idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [OpenNETCF serial classes](http://www.opennetcf.com/FreeSoftware/OpenNETCFIOSerial/tabid/252/Default.aspx)? Not sure if that has the precise feature you need but IMO it's better overall.

Call me crazy but I swear the CF version does weird things with threads.

Comment: Yes, I tried it but they contain too much classes for the simple feature I look for.

And .. yes, it does weird things ..